# Showing reference link in whole page

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I'm learning a step by step website. In the navigation section, I'm linking the Home, About Us, Contact Us, Rates, Services pages using  code, but when I link this on the About Us and Rates pages, the whole content text page is linked directing it to the Contact Us page. Don't know what's wrong with the code to unlink the body content of the page but keeping the regular nav link. 
Here's the code for the About US page only of which the Rates page uses the same code format. I could post both pages' codes if necessary. Thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


    <title>About Us: Home Cleaning Services in the SF Bay Area</title>


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</li>
                <li><a href="About US.html">About US</li>
                <li><a href="Services.html">Services</li>
                <li><a href="Rates.html">Rates</li>
                <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact US</li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <h2>We Talk Cleaning</h2>
        <p>With a growing economy and a vibrant style of life, the SF Bay area has become home for professionals, families, artists and everyone who wants to be part of this great region. Due to this, it’s very difficult to devote time to clean or organize our space where we live or work. Sometimes we say to ourselves we will get to clean up our stubborn room or bathroom, but we don’t get to do it because you don’t have the time or the least thing you would like to do in your free time is to get to the obstinate place.</p>

        <p> With Sparking Cleaning Services, we’ll make your life easier by providing a spotless and clean place for you to work or relax. One less thing to worry about in your life.</p>

        <img src="Images/100_0016.jpg" alt="San Francisco View">
  </body>
  <footer>All Rights Reserved 2016</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct form would be

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="About US.html">About US</a></li>
<li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="Rates.html">Rates</a></li>
 <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact US</a></li>
```

the reason your code is not working is because th e `<a>` tag includes everything between its starting and closing tags but since your'e not closing it its turning the whole content of the html page into a link

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was so simple and I seriously believed I had </a> closing tag on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free online HTML validator, like [html5.validator.nu](https://html5.validator.nu/) to help you spot the syntax errors. Choose "Text field" and paste in your HTML. Atm you have 6 errors, some might be the same. `Error 2) "Error: Unclosed element a"`, like @Immortal Dude said.

Comment: Thank you for providing that useful tool.

Comment: @AlfredoD If you like the tool please give me a +1 vote.